# check unique validate more readable and strong

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to make sure each date only can have one room sku of a room.

Here's my logic.

If there's no SKU of a room on a day => OK
If there's only ONE SKU of a room on a day, then check if the sku is equals to itself.
If so => OK
If not => Fail

I just think my logic is not so strong and hard to understand.

I bet there is a good solution to do so on RoR.

```
class RoomSku < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :room
  validate :should_be_unique_in_one_day

  def should_be_unique_in_one_day
    skus_on_this_day = _get_skus_on_this_day
    if skus_on_this_day.count==0
        nil
    elsif skus_on_this_day.count==1 and skus_on_this_day.first.id = self.id
        nil
    else
        errors.add(:departure_at, I18n.t("already_exists_on_the_same_day"))
    end
  end

  def _get_skus_on_this_day
    self.class.where(room_id: self.room_id, date: self.date)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is a scoped uniqueness validation

```
validates :date, uniqueness: { scope: :room_id }
```

Alternatively, if the error must be applied to `departure_at`, you could do something like this:

```
def should_be_unique_in_one_day
  errors.add(:departure_at, I18n.t("already_exists_on_the_same_day")) if RoomSku.where(room_id: room_id, date: date).where.not(id: id).exists?
end
```